# How to reproduce c++ negative indexing behavior with 2D array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to convert a c++ repo I found to js. But I ran across a roadblock.
the author of the original c++ code is indexing into a 2d array with a negative -1 when `i` and `j` are equal to 0 `arr2d[i-1][j]`, `arr2d[i][j-1]`. I thought this was a bug but the code runs and gives the correct results as intended. My knowledge of c++ is pretty limited and I know you can't access values in an array with negative indices in js.

I created a small test with c++ to try and understand what's going

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double map[3][3] = {{.123412,.452105,1},{.52342,-.56326,.904},{.1262,.14268,-.7411}};

    cout<<map[-1][1]; 

    return 0;
}
```

`map[-1][1]`   returns  1       (the first array last value)
`map[-1][0]`   returns  .452105 (the first array middle value)
`map[-1][-1]`  returns  .123412 (the first array first value)

Can someone help me understand what's happing and is there any way I can reproduce this behavior to get the same result in JavaScript?

Comment: You cannot in C++ either. You were right the original code is bugged. But bugged code sometimes gets 'lucky' and runs correctly anyway. This is because this kind of bug in C++ leads to *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: As you can see [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b2028f9f2c530a5) a different compiler behaves differently to yours, producing garbage numbers instead of your predictable numbers. This is what is meant by undefined behaviour.

Comment: So what you have to do is work out the rules by which your compiler interprets your code (you seem to have made good progress on that) and then implement those rules in a way that does not rely on negative indexes.

Comment: Probably easiest to add a function to get an item at an index and have that function implement whatever rules you need for dealing with out of bounds indexed